# Create a JSON file and send it to other device using wifi direct

Tags: android, json, wifi

I'm trying to create an application that allows two devices to connect using wifi direct and send a message from one device to another in a JSON file format and then parse that file into a text view. So far I'm not concern about the wifi part because I know it's very difficult and I want to start with the "easy" part of my project. I have this code so far.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edtx1;
    TextView txvw1;
    TextView txvw2;
    TextView txvw3;
    TextView txvw4;
    TextView txvw5;
    Button btn;
    String Message;
    String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edtx1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                txvw1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                txvw2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                txvw3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                txvw4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                txvw5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                //txvw1.setText(edtx1.getText().toString());
                makeJSON();
            }
        });
    }

    public JSONArray makeJSON() {
        JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
        try {

            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();

            //Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
            //String ts = tsLong.toString();

            jObj.put("Created_on:", currentDateTimeString);
            jObj.put("Sent_by:", Build.MODEL);
            jObj.put("MAC_Address:", macAddress);
            jObj.put("Number_of_Hops:", 1);
            jObj.put("Message:", edtx1.getText());

            txvw1.setText(jObj.getString("Created_on:"));
            txvw2.setText(jObj.getString("Sent_by:"));
            txvw3.setText(jObj.getString("MAC_Address:"));
            txvw4.setText(jObj.getString("Number_of_Hops:"));
            txvw5.setText(jObj.getString("Message:"));

            jArr.put(jObj);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e);
        }

        return jArr;
    }
}
```

I want to have a button and when clicked just send the information on the edittext to the json object called message. So at the end i will have something like this

```
{
  "Created on": Date,
  "Sent By": "name",
  "MAC Address": "FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF",
  "Number of Hops": "This number I will figure it out later",
  "Message": "Message"
}
```

And then send that file to the other device.

UPDATE:

I just edited the code above and now it's kind of working, at least I think is doing what i want. The problem here is with the device name and the MAC address. I know that now the MAC address cannot be taken within the app but I can just fill in that part and make it static. But how can i retrieve the name of the device for example my device is called "Daniel" how can i have that retrieved with a code?

Answer (score 0):

*I haven't tested this out, but this might help.*

Here are the official docs for using wifi-direct in case you need them

[android docs: wifi-direct](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html#receiver)

You can try to send your json object over as a string (its what i have to do when i POST to my server) and on the other side parse it like a standard json.

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.appendQueryParameter("key_1", "value_1");
builder.appendQueryParameter("key_2", "value_2");
String json = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
```

Once you have a class built you can get the data from it and then set with .setText()

let me know if you need an example on how to do that.

--- EDIT ---

as far was getting your device name, i found this snippet of code that should work for you, as long as you are ok with asking for bluetooth permission.

add this to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

and in your code

```
public String getPhoneName(){ 
    BluetoothAdapter myDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    String deviceName = myDevice.getName();     
    return deviceName;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Thomas. I've managed to create the Json Object and show it in the same device (this, with testing porpoises). I'm gonna edit my code so you can take a look at it and tell me if there is something i can do to improve it. Actually, I'm not even sure whether I am creating the json object or just posting it on the view before creating.

Comment: Thomas thanks again for your help I used the code you posted to get the name of the device and it worked. Now the app is creating the JSON file and now I'm going for the wifi direct connection part of it so if you have any code or tutorial that I use I would appreciate it.